# Edit the Foundation top-bar breakpoint, works but menu icon disappears

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

I'm using Zurb Foundation 5 for my website, but I need to change the top-bar breakpoint, since I have more menu items than what fits inside container.

I've googled and found out that I can overwrite this setting with the following(set BEFORE importing foundation):

```
$topbar-breakpoint: 880px; 
$topbar-media-query: "only screen and (min-width: #{$topbar-breakpoint})";
```

This makes the main menu disappear at 880px, but no menu icon(burger icon) shows up until the default breakpoint 40.063em(it is set to display: none, see screenshot below).

https://www.dropbox.com/s/3as00ir47aluh4b/Screenshot%202014-05-12%2014.32.43.png

Any suggestions how I can change the breakpoint using scss?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

You should modify foundation settings only if you have really good reason and there is no other way.  Use this markup instead(It's  the official way):

```html
<nav class="top-bar show-for-large-up" data-topbar="">
   <!-- menu items for the wide screen -->
</nav>

<nav class="top-bar hide-for-large-up" data-topbar="">
   <!-- menu items for the medium and small screen -->
</nav>
```

It should be compatible with the future versions of the Foundation out of the box and save you a lot of time in maintenance and  you will have less bugs to catch.

Comment: No, doesn't look like it. Here's my header section: [http://codepen.io/schikulski/pen/isBIK](http://codepen.io/schikulski/pen/isBIK)

Comment: @simen Btw foundation has a lot of commented out setting which can conflict if you use them simultaneously, especially breakpoints. And it's really hard to detect all the problems without checking each element with the each possible screen.

Comment: I see. But I thought the point with top-bar was the automatically generated mobile menu? On [Foundation's website](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html) you can se that the menu collapses into mobile menu without any additional markup for the mobile menu. Using the show-for-large-up and hide-for-large-up requireds me to render two sets of menus. What I need is Foundation to collapse into mobile menu a few pixels before the default. Everything else works perfectly out of the box in this case.

Comment: @simen check their top bar source. It the same code as mine because i took it there. I just changed visibility options.

Comment: Yeah, I'm starting to think the same thing, that my html is wrong or something. Feel free to check [my source code here](http://elverum-kulturskole.dev.joss.as/) u: stack p: overflow. This is driving me nuts.

Comment: @simen  Foundation has hamburger menu icon always visible. They just hide it's bar with it and other menu items and show another one for different size.

Comment: Not here. If you [look at my screenshot here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3as00ir47aluh4b/Screenshot%202014-05-12%2014.32.43.png) you can se that it's set to display: none; at 40.063em